# MSGraph/GraphServiceClient OneDrive uploading file to specific Site and/or Folder with C#

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

Blockquote

I have the following code which works fine and uploads the file to the Root Shared Directory.

```
    var uploadedFile = await graphClient.Drive.Root
                                  .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                                  .Content
                                  .Request()
                                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
```

However, I haven't been able to work out, how to upload a file to another Site or Folder created in SharePoint/OneDrive.

Here is the code I am trying to use where I have created a new Communication Site in Sharepoint named "DocumentUpload" but it errors.

```
    var uploadedFile = await graphClient.Sites["DocumentUpload"].Drive.Root
                                  .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                                  .Content
                                  .Request()
                                  .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
```

When I use the above code, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: invalidRequest
> Message: Invalid hostname for this tenancy
> Inner error:
> AdditionalData:
> date: 2022-02-28T13:17:25
> request-id: {Guid}
> client-request-id: {Guid}
> ClientRequestId: {Guid}
> '

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? Does manually uploading to SPS/OneDrive work? When you change site where and how are you instantiating the graphClient?

Comment: Could you share the code how do you try to upload file to a specific site including the error? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have edit the description to show the code I am trying to use to upload a file to a new Site and also shows the error I get

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Site Id, I had to do a GET request where I pass in the hostname e.g. xxxx.sharepoint.com and the relative-path e.g. sites/DocumentUpload as shown below.

Then I get a response back which I can use in the graphClient.Sites call I was confused about where I was passing in "DocumentUpload" instead of the Site Id which ends up looking like this "xxxx.sharepoint.com,{Guid},{Guid}"

```
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/DocumentUpload"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {_authResult.AccessToken}");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var siteDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteDetails>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        ...

        if (fileInfo.Length < LARGE_FILE_SIZE)
        {
            // upload the file to OneDrive
            var uploadedFile = await graphClient.Sites[siteDetails.id].Drive.Root
                                          .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                                          .Content
                                          .Request()
                                          .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
        }
    }
...
    class SiteDetails
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string webUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

After making this change, the Document uploads fine to that path.